# Flash refreshes when hide/show using the jquery tabs plugin?

Tags: jquery, flash

```
<div id="target">
<object height="100%" width="100%" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="main.swf" id="myContent" style="visibility: visible;"></object>
</div>
```

When the jquery tabs plugin `$('#target').hide()` then `$('#target').show()` ,the main.swf is refreshed automatically,how to avoid this kind of refreshing?

**UPDATE**

Anyone knows of a jquery tabs plugin that can avoid this kind of issue,say,it doesn't call `hide/show` internally?

Answer (score 2):

I think it is because browser reloads the content of div each time hide/show it.

Try this instead:

```
$('#target').css('visibility', 'hidden'); //hide
$('#target').css('visibility', 'visible'); //show
```

You should notice, that when using 'visibility', the space where element was will not be taken by other elements, the element just becomes invisible, not disappears. this can be fixed by using absolute position.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Flash is reloaded when you play with the display of flash containers.
You can either set the width and height to 0px or set the location of the container to some negative coordinates way off the screen (that's the method I use)

```
$("#target").css("width", "0px");
$("#target").css("height", "0px");
$("#target").css("left", "-500px");
$("#target").css("top", "-500px");
```

Comment: It's a problem indeed. What you should do is put the flash in an absolute positioned container and do the positioning trick upon the tab change event.

Comment: Are you sure that the container is absolute positioned hierarchically outside of the tab?